# Jquery duplicate input fields by class

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, jquery

Not quite sure how to arrange this question.

Basically, I have a page with 4 forms all in separate tabs, (3 for each department and an admin overview with all forms on), what I would like to do is once the input has changed in one of the 3 departmental forms duplicate that input into the same field in the admin form.

What I'm currently using is the following

```
jQuery(".volume").keyup(function(){
        var volume = jQuery(".volume").val();
        jQuery('.volume').val(volume);
        });
```

this works fine in it self, but what I would like is to be able to have a little function like this that automatically works on any input, textarea and select.

Would anyone be able to advise me on how to put something like that together?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Apologies, copied and edited the wrong snippet. was originally duplicating too another ID. edited to reflect that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
jQuery("input").keyup(function() {
    var volume = jQuery(this).val();
    jQuery("input[name=" + jQuery(this).attr("name") + "]").val(volume);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, had to make a few tweaks to get it working by name, works well though!jQuery("input").keyup(function() {
    var vol = jQuery(this).val();
    var cla = jQuery(this).attr("name");
    var name = 'input[name="'+cla+'"]';
    jQuery(name).val(vol);
});

Comment: you're welcome - updated the answer to reflect your case better

Comment: didn't have much luck with prop, however attr worked a treat.

Comment: what version of jQuery are you using?